# R commandArgs(TRUE) returns string instead of array?

Tags: r, command-line, command-line-arguments

**The Script**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/Rscript --slave
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
print(args);
```

**The Shell Command**

```
~/Rscript my_script.R hello 10 3
```

**The Output**

```
[1] "hello" "0"     "10"
```

I was expecting an array like:

```
[1] "hello"
[2] "0"
[3] "10"
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how a vector is printed in R, the same as if you'd created it like this:

```
> c("hello", "10", "3")
[1] "hello" "10"    "3"
```

Try

```
print(args[1])
print(args[2])
print(args[3])
```

and you'll see that each accesses the appropriate string.

Answer (score 2):

From `?commandArgs` the value returned is:

> A character vector containing the name of the executable and the
>   user-supplied command line arguments

The output you showed is the standard way R displays vectors:

```
> c("Hello", "10", "3")
[1] "Hello" "10"    "3"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the values in args as numeric, don't forget to convert it as the commandArgs gets you a vector of strings. Ex.

> N <- as.numeric(Args[3])

returns you 10 not "10".